# Use value of another field as default value for left join

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, default-value

I have the following 3 tables:

```
users
| id | name  | address  |
|----+-------+----------+
| 1  | user1 | address1 |
| 2  | user2 | address2 |

locations
| id | user_id | name      |
|----+---------+-----------+
| 1  | 1       | location1 |
| 2  | 1       | location2 |
| 3  | 2       | location3 |

orders
| id | user_id | from_id | to_id |
|----+---------+---------+-------+
| 1  | 1       | 1       | 2     |
| 2  | 1       | 1       | 0     |
```

from_id or to_id can have 0, meaning that user's address was used in this case.

Executing a 'naive' join on these tables:

```
SELECT u.name uname, fl.location flocation, tl.location tlocation
FROM   users u, orders o, locations fl, locations tl
WHERE  u.id = o.user_id
  AND  o.from_id = fl.id
  AND  o.to_id = tl.id
```

doesn't show records with 0:

```
user1 | location1 | location2
```

what I would like to see is the following data:

```
user1 | location1 | location2
user1 | location1 | address1
```

Using mysql, is there a way to extend the join to show such results ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend abandoning the "comma" syntax for the join operation; use the JOIN keyword, and move the join predicates to an `ON` clause rather than the `WHERE` clause.

To get all rows from `orders` returned, whether or not there is a "matching" row from the other tables, you can use an outer join operation.

In the SELECT list, you can test whether the `location` column from `locations` IS NULL, and return the `address` column from the `user` table when it is, using the `COALESCE` function.

```
SELECT u.name uname
     , COALESCE(fl.location,u.address) flocation
     , COALESCE(tl.location,u.address) tlocation
  FROM orders o
  LEFT
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id = o.user_id
  LEFT
  JOIN locations fl
    ON fl.id = o.from_id
  LEFT
  JOIN locations tl
    ON tl.id = o.to_id
```

The `COALESCE(x,y)` function is essentially shorthand for 'CASE WHEN x IS NULL THEN y ELSE x END`.

There's a corner case there, what if a matching row in the `locations` table is found, but the `location` column actually contains a NULL.

To more precisely match your specification, you could test for a value of "`0`" in the `to_id` column of the `orders` table:

```
SELECT u.name uname
     , IF(o.from_id = 0, u.address, fl.location) flocation
     , IF(o.to_id   = 0, u.address, tl.location) tlocation
  FROM orders o
  LEFT
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id = o.user_id
  LEFT
  JOIN locations fl
    ON fl.id = o.from_id
  LEFT
  JOIN locations tl
    ON tl.id = o.to_id
```

But there's a corner case there; what if there is a row in `locations` that has an id value of "`0`".

The normative pattern would be to test for whether a row was returned from the `locations` table by checking a column that is guaranteed to be NOT NULL if a match is found, and will be NULL if a match is not found:

```
SELECT u.name uname
     , IF(fl.id IS NULL, u.address, fl.location) flocation
     , IF(tl.id IS NULL, u.address, tl.location) tlocation
  FROM orders o
  LEFT
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id = o.user_id
  LEFT
  JOIN locations fl
    ON fl.id = o.from_id
  LEFT
  JOIN locations tl
    ON tl.id = o.to_id
```

All three of those queries will return identical results for the "normal" cases; they just differ in how the "corner cases" are handled.

In summary:

- use `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` operations with `orders` as the driving table.
- use conditional expressions in the SELECT list to determine which column value to return

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL should do it:

```
SELECT u.name uname, IF(fl.id, fl.location, u.address) AS flocation, IF(tl.id, tl.location, u.address) AS tlocation
FROM users u
    INNER JOIN orders o ON u.id = o.user_id
    LEFT JOIN locations fl ON o.from_id = fl.id
    LEFT JOIN locations tl ON o.to_id = tl.id;
```

And if I may make a suggestion, I would recommend that you not use the WHERE clause as a way to join tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.name uname, fl.location flocation, tl.location tlocation
FROM users u 
left join orders o
          on u.id = o.user_id
left join locations fl
          on o.from_id = fl.id
left join locations tl
          on o.to_id = tl.id
```

This will give you data for all users.

And as **Tim Burch** suggested, its best to use the ANSI SQL Syntax.

Answer (score 0):

To use the user's address as a default for both the from and the to names, you can do a left join and use `COALESCE` to replace nulls with the address;

```
SELECT 
  u.name uname, 
  COALESCE(fl.name, u.address) flocation, 
  COALESCE(tl.name, u.address) tlocation
FROM users u
JOIN orders o ON u.id = o.user_id
LEFT JOIN locations fl ON o.from_id = fl.id
LEFT JOIN locations tl ON o.to_id = tl.id
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa84c/6).